# Visual Studio datagridview having problem to get minumum value of cells and the other cells to a text box

Tags: datagridview, visual-studio-2017, min

I face problem while tying to get min value from datagridview and output to a label.text/textbox.text.

[This is my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmR20.png)

```
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim maxname As String = ""
    Dim maxgd As String = ""
    Dim maxvalue As String = ""

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        If i = 0 Then
            max = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value

        End If

        If max < DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value Then
            maxvalue = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            maxname = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            maxgd = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
        End If


    Next

    HmsLabel.Text = maxname.ToString()
    GDLabel.Text = maxgd.ToString()
    AMLabel.Text = maxvalue.ToString()

End Sub
```

The code above works for the max value and the name and grade output

However the code for min didn't work:

```
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim minname As String = ""
    Dim mingd As String = ""
    Dim minvalue As String = ""

    For l = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        If l = 0 Then
            min = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(4).Value
        End If

        If min > DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(4).Value Then
            minvalue = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(4).Value
            minname = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(0).Value
            mingd = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(5).Value
        End If

    Next

    LAMLabel.Text = minvalue.ToString()
    LMSLabel.Text = minname.ToString()
    LGDLabel.Text = mingd.ToString()
```

[The output of max value and its name and also the fail output of min value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q0kZ.png)

I have try using this code to find the min value but it works for the min value but I don't know how to make the min name and min grade appear in the textbox too

```
LAMLabel.Text = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                 Where row.Cells(4).FormattedValue.ToString(<>String.Empty Select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(4).FormattedValue)).Min().ToString()
```

Thank you for helping me , appreciate very much.

Comment: You may want to re-think your logic in both methods… Example… You may want to test when the FIRST row in the grid contains the min or max value… hint… the min/max variables do not get set. In other words… in the top code you claim… _”The code above works for the max value and the name and grade output”_ … this is not true if the FIRST row contains the MAX value.

Comment: OK I have solve this problem. Anyway, Thank for helping me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for my own question. Just add `=` after `min>` for the max value. Also add `=` after `max<`.

```
Dim min As Integer
Dim minname As String = ""
Dim mingd As String = ""
Dim minvalue As String = ""

For l = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
    If l = 0 Then
        min = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(4).Value
    End If

    If min >= DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(4).Value Then
        minvalue = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(4).Value
        minname = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(0).Value
        mingd = DataGridView1.Rows(l).Cells(5).Value
    End If

Next

LAMLabel.Text = minvalue.ToString()
LMSLabel.Text = minname.ToString()
LGDLabel.Text = mingd.ToString()
```